# Spark numoutputrows metric shows -1

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using structured streaming with kafka output sink.

I log the records written to kafka by using SinkProgess.numoutputrows metric:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/SinkProgress.html

The result is that most of the time the numoutputrows reports the correct numbers. However sometimes I see a bunch of -1. And because of this the metric itself is totally useless.

**Now in the doc they states:**

```
numOutputRows Number of rows written to the sink or -1 for Continuous Mode (temporarily) or Sink V1 (until decommissioned).
```

What this means? I use microbatches but not Continuous Mode.
What they mean by temporarily? What is Sink V1? What they mean by 'until decomissioned'.

Totally unclear.

**edit:**

- And it is not a solution to simply ignore the -1s because even then the numbers doesn't add up.
- If I start the app and no -1 show up then the final result is correct 100% of the time.
- Seems these -1s swallow the correct numbers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an expected behaviour. Reference : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33359?focusedCommentId=17227029&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17227029